# Bootstrap: Keeping content responsive when using an offcanvas sidebar

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

**Here is the current working example of what I have going on:**

[Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/z3wfct19/2/)

**This is what I would like to do:**

The content (i.e. the three circles, or anything inside the `<section>`) is responsive and resizes itself to fit the current browser size. Try making the Fiddle render window small and notice how the circles stack.

Now, when I click the hamburger menu, I want the same thing to happen. The sidebar that appears is using an "[offcanvas reveal](http://www.jasny.net/bootstrap/examples/navmenu-reveal/)" to push itself into view, but is not triggering responsive behavior; it simply shoves all content right off the edge of the page. How can I remedy this?

**Here is my code:**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <header>
        <div class="navmenu navmenu-default navmenu-fixed-right">
            <ul class="nav navmenu-nav">
                <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </header>
    <div class="canvas">
        <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="offcanvas" data-recalc="false" data-target=".navmenu" data-canvas=".canvas">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <!-- content here -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you add a little more detail. Seems to vague to understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: What in particular seems vague? I can clear up any specific questions you may have.

Comment: I understand what you're trying to do now. Do you want the navbar to float over the DIV with the circles and ABC? And not push the content off screen, or do you want to the DIV to stack content in a vertical fashion when the 'hamburger' menu is clicked.

Comment: The latter. I want the content to resize (i.e. continue being responsive) when the hamburger is clicked and the sidebar pops out. As it stands, clicking the hamburger simply shifts the whole page to the right.

Comment: The circles will never resize because they are set to static widths and heights. If you make them pngs instead you can then set them to a percentage and then they won't stack.

Comment: I don't want the circles to resize. I'm not sure where you got that from. I'm talking about keeping the content responsive. Shrink the JSFiddle render window to observe them stacking vertically for mobile/tablet devices with small screens.

Comment: The JASNY off canvas menu, as well as almost all off canvas menus use something like CSS transform: translateY(y) and z-index to push the menu on/off to screen, and JS/Jquery to trigger a change in the z-index to reveal the menu. I am assuming that what you are experiencing is the way this particular version of the JASNY off canvas menu works is by actually pushing the content on the Y axis instead of the menu, which is causing your bootstrap columns to collapse? Like stated above your question is a little unclear.

Comment: @DestinationDesigns If I'm understanding you correctly, I think you are right on the money with your assumptions.

Comment: there are lots of other solutions out there that push the menu over the content instead, probably your best option. I have several that I use because i never cared for the JASNY solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the question it is not clear what you are looking for. I have created a possible solution for your issue

http://jsfiddle.net/5vqu5082/

```
.canvas-slid.canvas{
    width: 30%;
}
```

Comment: It looks like you pretty much understand what I want -- for the content to remain in the viewport, even when the hamburger menu is invoked and the sidebar becomes visible.  I don't want the main content pushed off to the side; I want it to reorganize for the current viewport, just as a responsive site would do.  That said, this may indeed be a possible solution. I'm going to play with it a bit.

Comment: The JASNY off canvas menu solutions dont work that way, see my comment above. Probably best to use a different solution that pushes the menu over the content instead

Comment: Do you have any suggestions for different solutions? Foundation, perhaps? Or is there a more elegant way of doing this with pure jQuery?

Comment: hold on, I'll post up what I use. It will just take me a minute to trim out the content

Answer (score 1):

working demo of an off canvas menu as i described in my comments: http://jsfiddle.net/b6nopc8e/

HTML:

```
<div id="site-wrapper" class="container-fluid">
    <div id="menuToggle">
        <btn id="menuButton" class="main-menu btn btn-transparent pull-right" data-transition="boring">
        <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v fa-3x"></i><br />
        <div>menu</div><div style="display:none;">close</div></btn>
    </div>
    <nav id="site-menu">
        <ul class="nav">
            <li><a href="/">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="/">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="/">Link</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>  
    <div id="site-canvas">
        <div id="mainbody" class="container-fluid">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h1>Hello World</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#menuButton {
    width: 45px;
    height: 45px;
}

/********************************
/* OFF CANVAS MENU 
/*******************************/
.show-nav #site-canvas {
    transform: translateX(-330px);      
    transform: translate3d(-330px, 0, 0);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-330px);      
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-330px, 0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-330px);      
    -ms-transform: translate3d(-330px, 0, 0);
}

.boring #site-menu {
    transform: translateX(0);   
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);   
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);    
    -ms-transform: translateX(0);   
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);    
}
.boring .show-nav #site-menu {
    transition: 900ms ease all;      
    transform: translateX(-330px);
    transform: translate3d(-330px, 0, 0);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-330px);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-330px, 0, 0);   
    -ms-transform: translateX(-330px);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(-330px, 0, 0);   
}

.boring .show-nav #site-canvas {
    transform: translateX(0);   
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);   
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translateX(0);   
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

/********************************
/* WIREFRAME ELEMENTS
/*******************************/
#site-wrapper {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

#menuToggle {
    margin-right: 10px;
    position: fixed;
        top: 0; right: 0;
    z-index: 888;
}

#site-menu {
    background-color: #999;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0; right: -330px;
    width: 300px;   
    z-index: 777;   
}

#site-menu:after { z-index: 999; }

#site-canvas {
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    height: 100%;   
    transform: translateX(0);   
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);    
    width: 100%;
}
```

JQUERY

```
/********************************
/* OFF CANVAS MENU
/*******************************/
(function($){
  jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        var special = ['reveal', 'top', 'boring', 'perspective', 'extra-pop'];
            // Toggle Nav on Click
            $('.main-menu').click(function() {
                var transitionClass = jQuery(this).data('transition');
                if ($.inArray(transitionClass, special) > -1) {
                    $('body').removeClass();
                    $('body').addClass(transitionClass);
                } else {
                    $('body').removeClass();
                    $('#site-canvas').removeClass();
                    $('#site-canvas').addClass(transitionClass);
                }
                $('#site-wrapper').toggleClass('show-nav'); 
                $('.main-menu i').toggleClass('fa-ellipsis-v fa-ellipsis-h');
                $(".main-menu div").html("menu");
                $('.main-menu div').toggle();
                return false;
            }); 
    });
})(jQuery);

/********************************
/* OFF CANVAS MENU HEIGHT
/*******************************/
(function($){
  jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            $('#site-canvas').css({'min-height':($(window).height())+'px'});
            $(window).resize(function(){
                $('#site-canvas').css({'min-height':($(window).height())+'px'});
            });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Some notes: This menu is on the right. but by changing the translate numbers you can move it to the right. This is a really quick rough strip down so the code may be a bit messy.

Comment: Appreciate the effort, truly. But it's not really what I'm looking for. It doesn't fit the nature of the request at all in that it fails to preserve responsiveness in the content. That said, I'll award it the solution if there's simply no actual way to accomplish what I requested. However, for the moment, I'm in hot pursuit of a possible solution.